# I'm using Indesign - the background is black yet when I print pdf it shows white

Tags: adobe-indesign, print-design, pdf, page-layout, background

I'm using Indesign - the background is black yet when I print the PDF it shows white.

How can I fix this please?

Comment: It's a bit hard to answer with so little details! Can you tell us what you've tried to fix the issue so far and what didn't work? It could be a bug, some setting on your printer to save ink (eg. remove backgrounds) or some setting somewhere in InDesign! So many possibilities! Please edit your question and add more details if possible. Also, confirm that the "print a PDF" is really printing a PDF and not exporting a PDF!

Comment: exporting a pdf from indesign - the background to the document is black yet the pdf is white after exporting. i havent changed any settings...

Comment: your advice is much appreciated

Comment: What have you tried to fix your issue? Did you verify if your background is on a layer that won't print (layer options)? Did you verify if there's some  knockout trapping somehow on that part of the design? How did you do that black background? etc. It's still lacking details!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is my background white when exported as PDF in InDesign?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/8124/why-is-my-background-white-when-exported-as-pdf-in-indesign)

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like your `[Paper]` swatch is set to black. You can colour your paper with this swatch and preview your design on coloured paper. If you set the `[Paper]` swatch to a colour (like black) it will only show up on your screen and never print.

To fix this. Double click on the [Paper] swatch and set all ink percentages to 0%. Then add a new layer with a new rectangle covering the whole page. Apply the [Black] swatch to this rectangle and move the new layer to the bottom.

Comment: I took the liberty of incorporating that comment into your post. Thanks! Welcome to GD.SE and thanks for your answer. If you have any questions about the site, have a look at the [help] or feel free to ping one of us in [chat] once your reputation allows you to go there (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!