# Why isn't content displaying on a previously-downloaded PDF?

Tags: adobe-acrobat

Lately, my Adobe Acrobat DC on my Windows 10 PC has taken to not displaying significant chunks of text and/or (theme)images from various PDFs. I've only confirmed this to occur on PPT pdfs thus far. In the image below, the whole white area is supposed to be filled with text and non-white BG. The first time I saw this, I thought it was because I hadn't downloaded the fontface used, but now it seems to be occurring on a "standard" fontface and on a document I downloaded well before this started occurring. What's going on and how do I fix this? I've already tried redownloading, unblocking the files, and rebooting. Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The most similar question ([PDF not displaying on Windows, looks okay on a Mac](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/83123/pdf-not-displaying-on-windows-looks-okay-on-a-mac)) was posted 3 years ago, cites a different program of origin (InDesign vs PPT), and relates more specifically to images/BG colors than text, but I'll post the answer here too just in case.

Adobe Acrobat may automatically enable **Accessibility > Replace Document Colors**, causing the above glitch. Simply open Preferences (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>) and disable the setting. Acrobat doesn't have to be rebooted for this to take effect.